# Neural Network in Swift

Tags: c++, swift, neural-network

Well, long story short, I was bored and decided to try to learn about Neural networks. I have been doing C# for a year and now that I am learning Swift, I preferred to continue with that language, and to follow this [tutorial](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html).

The problem is that it is in C (or C++ I am not sure) and that I don't know this language, and I clearly don't hae the courage to learn it now. By deducing, I understand things step-by-step but still, not all of them. So the purpose of this thread is for me to regularly edit my question with new subquestions (avoiding multiple posts) to convert this C++ project into swift. Is this against SO Rules ?

Here are my first ones:

- In **Structures** (see [here](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt6.html) for examples):

  C++ Code:

  ```
  struct SNeuron
  {
     int m_NumInputs; //var m_NumInputs:Int (Swift)

     vector<double> m_vecWeight; // var m_vecWeight:[Double] = [] (Swift)

     SNeuron(int NumInputs); // IS THS THE SAME AS init(numInputs:Int) ?

  };
  ```
- My **Sigmoid** function

  ```
  func Sigmoid(x:Double) -> Double
  {
      return 1/(1 + exp(-x))
  }
  ```

  (which is supposed to follow this function)

  ```
      inline double Sigmoid(double activation, double response); //inline ?
  ```
- What does **CParams::** means ?

  ```
        //add in the bias

        netinput += m_vecLayers[i].m_vecNeurons[j].m_vecWeight[NumInputs-1] *

                    CParams::dBias; //?
  ```
- Is **Vector.push_back()** "equals" to **Array.append** ?

  ```
    outputs.push_back(Sigmoid(netinput, CParams::dActivationResponse));
  ```

  translated in

  ```
    outputs.append(Sigmoid(netinput))
  ```
- Declaration of a function with a syntax I don't understand:

  ```
      int GetNumberOfWeights()const; //const ?
  ```

Well... I am only at the first code page of the tutorial so things may explain themselves in the future but still, if someone has some time to help me, it would be great !

Comment: You can't translate code from a language you don't understand. You also have to know your tools (like commands and functions to find things in files).

Comment: With C# I manage to understand things slowly, and the tutorial is well done so I still want to try

Comment: I am not an expert in SO rules, but your question seems much to broad to me. Also *"regularly editing your question with new subquestions"* would make it impossible to provide a definite answer that is accepted eventually.

Comment: You are also mixing question about the C++ code in the tutorial (*"What does CParams:: means ?"*) with question about the Swift language.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the definite answer problem. But for the mixed questions, I just try to understand the c++ syntax to be able to convert it later without th need to post multiple different questions

Comment: So your question is how to translate code from one language that you don't know and *"don't have the courage to learn"* (C++) to another language that you are about to learn (Swift)? - Even for questions about the meaning of `inline`, `CParams::dBias`, or `vector.push_back()` it would probably be expected that you make yourself familiar with the basics of C++ first.

Comment: I am learning swift, but I have already done about 15 little projects so I am getting familiar with it. Okay so the main Idea is "Go learn C++." right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to know C#, here is a good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL29C61214F2146796) on ANN, that you may be able to convert in Swift after doing it in C#